# Saving for loop outputs to different FITS files

Tags: python

Hi so I'm working with a bunch of FITS files in a for loop (to average them), and I was just wondering if there is a way to save the loop outputs as new/individual FITS files?

I can't seem to figure out how to have the output name iterate and match the actual data outputs.

So I want the loop to save the 10 different outputs as: bfdiffs1.fits, bfdiffs2.fits, etc...

Thanks!

Sample code below:

```
btotal = np.asarray([bias1data,bias2data,bias3data,bias4data,bias5data,
bias6data,bias7data,bias8data,bias9data,bias10data,
bias11data,bias12data,bias13data,bias14data,bias15data])

ftotal = np.asarray([flat1data,flat2data,flat3data,flat4data,flat5data,
          flat6data,flat7data,flat8data,flat9data,flat10data])

mv = np.max(btotal, axis=0)
sums = np.sum(btotal, axis=0)
sub = sums-mv
btotalavg = sub/(len(btotal)-1)

i=0
for fdata in ftotal:
    bfdiff = abs(fdata-btotalavg)
    for bfdata in bfdiff:
        newname = 'bfdiff%s' %i
        for w in newname:
            hdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(bfdiff)
            hdu.writeto(w+'.fits')
```

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason you're looping over every character in your filename.  You're writing:

```
newname = 'bfdiff%s' % i
```

and then

```
for w in newname:
    ...
```

What were you expecting that additional `for` loop to do?  All it does is loop over every character in `newname`.

Incidentally, you use a filename format template `'bfdiff%s'` but then later additionally append `+ '.fits'`.  You can do this all in one fell swoop with a format string like `'bfdiff%s.fits'`.

Your other problem is that you're not actually incrementing your loop variable `i` which I assume you want to do in order for each file to have a different filename.